# Definition of a continuous group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, continuous-homomorphisms

I was reading about Lie groups, and whenever they are defining a Lie group homomorphism they state it is a group homomorphism between Lie groups that is continuous. I tried looking for a definition of continuity of a group homomorphism but I couldn't find any concrete definition. I might be wrong, but what I understood was that a group homomorphism between Lie groups is continuous when the codomain is connected. What condition should a group homomorphism of Lie groups have to accomplish so that I know it is continuous? Is there any generalized condition a group homomorphism between any two groups (not necessarily Lie) needs to satisfy so that we can say it is continuous in its domain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Lie group comes with an associated topology: saying that the morphism is continuous is simply saying that the application is continuous with respect to said topology

Comment: Thanks. I'll review more about the continuity of maps between differentiable manifolds that preserve a group structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Lie groups are also manifolds, as the comment says they have a topology.

So if $G$ and $H$ are Lie groups, a map $f: G \rightarrow H$ is a continuous group homomorphism if it satisfies

$$f(xy)=f(x)f(y) \ \forall x, y\in G \textrm { (homomorphism) }$$
and
$$\forall U \subset H \textrm{ open }, f^{-1}(U)\subset G \textrm{ is open } \textrm{ (continuity)}.$$

I think Lie groups are by definition smooth manifolds, and then a Lie group homomorphism would be a continuous group homomorphism that is in fact smooth and not just continuous.

Comment: I agree, saying it's smooth seems more accurate for these homomorphisms. I only have an initial differential geometry background and reading about topology it's still a little tricky, but this helped. Thanks!